# Is the expectation of a stochastic process a continuous function in time?

Tags: convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, continuity

Suppose $ X = \left ( X_t \right )_{t\geq 0} $ is a stochastic process.

1) Under which conditions on $ X $ does
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \mathbb{E}\lvert X_t \rvert = \mathbb{E}\lvert X_0 \rvert
\end{equation}
hold?

2) Under which conditions on $ X $ does
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \mathbb{E}\lvert e^{X_t} \rvert = \mathbb{E}\lvert e^{X_0} \rvert
\end{equation}
hold?

Possible conditions I thought of are $ X $ being cadlag or $ X $ being a Levy process.

Thanks!